# Angular: On Refresh - Resources Not Found ( Auto-change the Request URL)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7, progressive-web-apps, angular7-router

***Problem Statement***

Steps Followed:

1. open http://localhost:4200 (index file get successfully loaded)
2. open http://localhost:4200/customers (UI successfully loaded)

Header: No Resource/File with Status Code 404)

Note the Request URL of manifest.json  http://localhost:4200/manifest.json

[image]

3. Press Refresh Button

Case 1: URL becomes http://localhost:4200/customers/ (only index file loads without UI for /customers)

Note the URL of manifest.json is http://localhost:4200/customers/manifest.json with Status Code 404

[image]

Case 2: Multiple Resouces Not Found because of the wrong Request URL

[image]

***Project Structure***
[image]

---

***index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/w3/w3css4w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/themify-icons/css/themify-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendors/selectFX/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/vendors/chosen/chosen.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../assets/vendors/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="/assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/vendors/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/vendors/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- //filters -->
    <script src="/assets/vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- //css effects -->
    <script src="/assets/vendors/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- //filters -->
    <script src="/assets/js/init-scripts/data-table/datatables-init.js"></script> 
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "MyAppName",
  "short_name": "MyAppName",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

***angular.json***

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyAppName": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyAppName",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppName:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyAppName:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyAppName:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyAppName-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyAppName:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MyAppName:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyAppName"
}
```

---

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//imports Component 

const routes: Routes = 
[
  {path:'customer/new',component:CreateCustomerAccountComponent,},
  {path:'customers',component:CustomersComponent},
  {path:'customers/:id/history',component:CustomerBuyHistoryComponent},
  {path:'items',component:ItemsComponent},
  {path:'item/new',component:CreateItemComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents=
[
  Components
]
```

---

```
***ng --version***

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/pwa                      0.12.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Comment: Did you add `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` to index.html?

Comment: @NikolaStekovic yes, I have added the index.html for reference.

Comment: Perhaps try a slash in your index.html  <base href="/">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a slash in your index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `/` in `<base href="/">` in *index.html* solved the issue.

### Why?

`<base href="/">` is your root base path, all the resources, and assets in your application are referenced based on this.

This means that your app would start from root folder i.e locally it would consider `localhost:4200/` and on a server it would consider root folder.

When you run your app, it may confuse your browser as your files are not at the root path and could through `404`.